# constructing Spark sql Datasets inside for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

TestDF is a data frame. can it be edited / altered 10 times inside for loop ?

Spark don't have options to edit and save back in same dataset.

java too don't have dynamic variable assignment.

Need to do something like this "Dataset `<Row>` testDF+(i+1) = testDF+(i)" (dynamic variables) or "Dataset `<Row>` testDF = testDF" (in same dataset) inside for loop.

Is there any way of looping spark DF inside for loop ?

```
String[] arraytest = schemaString.split(";");

for (int i=0;i < arraytest .length;i++) {
    String fieldName = arraytest[i];

    Dataset<Row> testDF+(i+1) = testDF+(i)
       .withColumn(fieldName, 
           functions.when(functions.col(fieldName).equalTo(""),"-99")
           .otherwise(functions.col(fieldName)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Accumulators for this

For Example you can use something like this

```
CollectionAccumulator<String> queryAccumulator = sparkSession.sparkContext().collectionAccumulator();


Dataset<Row> table= sparkSession.sql("select * from table");

    table.foreachPartition(partition->{
        while(partition.hasNext()){
            Row row = partition.next();
        String sql="select * from table where cond1= '"+row.getAs("cond1")+"' and cond2= '"+row.getAs("cond2")+"' order " +
                "by starttime desc limit 24";
            queryAccumulator.add(sql);}

    });
    logger.info("Queries to be executed are {}",queryAccumulator.value());
    Dataset<Row> limitedDataDf= queryAccumulator.value().stream().map(query-> sparkSession.sql(query)).reduce(Dataset::union).get();

    limitedDataDf.createOrReplaceTempView("SPARKJOBINFORMATION_LIMIT");
```